# Azure DNS: Where is it?

Tags: azure, dns

Is there a way on the management GUI to setup Azure DNS like you would setup all their other services?

The only instructions I can seem to find are for doing it on powershell or creating a DNS server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently the only way to set up Azure DNS is via Powershell or REST API! There is no GUI frontend. (I imagine it is on the Azure Team's todo list somewhere!

Answer (score 3):

If using a 3rd party tool is an option, may I suggest you take a look at [`Cloud Portam`](http://www.cloudportam.com). In short, it is a browser-based application for managing your Azure resources.

Recently we released Azure DNS management functionality in there. You can learn more about Azure DNS functionality in Cloud Portam here: http://www.cloudportam.com/features/azure-subscription/dns.

**Full Disclosure: I am builder behind this tool.**